# Is there an online service that can be used to programmatically verify a RS256 signed OAuth2 JWT?

Tags: rsa, jwt

I'm receiving a JWT from Microsoft Azure, and I need to verify it on my server. The JWT is signed using RS256, i.e. using asymmetrical private/public key encryption.

I know that various libraries exist that can be used to verify a JWT signature directly from our backend server. But I'm curious if it wouldn't be possible to verify the JWT signature using an online service? Since it's using RS256 and not HS256, only public keys are involved in the verification process, no private keys or other secrets.

It seems like it would be simple to put up a REST service that can take an asymmetrically signed JWT, verify the signature and give back true/false. But when Googling I can't find any such services. Not even from big names in the JWT-world, like `Auth0`.

Why is that? Is there some security concern with letting another server verify the JWT signature?

Comment: *Is there some security concern with letting another server verify the JWT signature?* You now have to trust the other server to give you an honest answer. That other server also has to be up and accessible.  And that security hit buys you nothing because verifying JWT signatures is easy.

Comment: In a perfect world where there are no constraints on languages, server configurations, developer time, legacy code interopability, etc. I'd agree. But sometimes reality is far, far away from the _"<package manager> install <shiny-new-jwt-library>"_ of online tutorials...